# Geany color scheme conf file: format and fields

Tags: themes, geany

I want to change the search result highlight of a Geany theme.

In the ~/.config/geany/colorschemes/ directory, we have *configuration files that I can only partially understand.

I have looked through the [Geany manual](https://www.geany.org/manual/) and [the GitHub offering](https://github.com/codebrainz/geany-themes), but I haven't found any detailed documentation on the format or fields of the file.

For example: many of the field names are self-explanatory, but some are not. And what effect do the Boolean fields have?

Comment: Could you put up an image of what you want to change to what as well as the name of the theme you're using?

Comment: @DKBose Isn't his question clear enough?

Answer (score 5):

So you open a Geany theme configuration file and you see something like this:

```
default=#fff;#1e1e1e;false;false
type=#2e8b57;;true
class=type
function=default
parameter=function
comment=#747474;#1e1e1e;false;true
```

*Generally*, the parameters for each category attribute are as follows:

```
[category] = [foreground color]; [background color]; [is Bold]; [is Italic]
```

There are exceptions in some cases where the boolean values determine when either the foreground and/or background colors are overridden (such as for a highlighted selection.)

So in my example above, "comment" is a medium gray color on dark gray background (same as default text) *and italicized*.

Optionally, you can duplicate an attribute by back-referencing the original definition ("class" is the same as "type", etc.)

Also from the geany-themes git page (https://github.com/geany/geany-themes/blob/master/ADDING-A-THEME.md):

> While there's no strict style guide for how the .conf file is formatted,
>   here's some notes about preferred style:
>
> - It's easiest to start by using an existing colour scheme that is
>     similar to the one you want to create/port.
> - Use HTML-style colours starting with a pound symbol (`#`), in
>     lower-case hex notation, compressing to 3 digits if possible. Examples:
>
>   - `#ff0`
>   - `#e4b211`
> - Use [named_colors] (see Geany Manual) where appropriate, if you want.

It may not be directly referenced, and a little tricky to find, but I did find more descriptive definitions in the online Geany Manual at https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#named-colors-section (It's under the section titled ***Special file filetypes.common***.)